# IOS How to 'PUT' text from UIText, and using blocks

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am very new to IOS. With the help of another managed to 'get' data from a third-party API and display in my table view, but now l want to write a number of strings from UIText fields, format based on the API docs and write to the server. The existing code that l have uses blocks. Can anyone provide a very simple example?

Below serves as a rough stab in the dark at decomposing what would be required:

Class 1 - VC class:

```
//User input from UIText field
```

I am assuming that l need to write the strings to a NSDictionary- object and key pairs, and using a block?

Call a method which resides in `Class 2`, which will request the data from the block in `Class 1`?

Class 2 - Model class:

```
//Format the data as per the API dictates
//'PUT' the string to the server
```

Here is what l have thus far:

URLOUTViewController.h Class

```
    //
//  URLOUTViewController.h
//  URLOUT
//
//  Created by Gregory Arden on 21/11/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Not Defined. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "URLOUT_Model.h"


@interface URLOUTViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *firstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *secondName;

- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

URLOUTViewController.m

```
//
//  URLOUTViewController.m
//  URLOUT
//
//  Created by Gregory Arden on 21/11/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Not Defined. All rights reserved.
//

#import "URLOUTViewController.h"
#import "URLOUT_Model.h"


@interface URLOUTViewController ()

//Private properties
@property (strong, nonatomic) URLOUT_Model *modelNewDroplet;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *userInput;

@end

@implementation URLOUTViewController

@synthesize userInput;
@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize secondName;

- (URLOUT_Model *) modelNewDroplet
{
    if (!_modelNewDroplet) _modelNewDroplet = [[URLOUT_Model alloc]init];
    return _modelNewDroplet;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [URLOUT_Model createDropletWithCompletion:^(NSDictionary *userInput) {
        self.modelNewDroplet = userInput;
    }];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender {

    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         self.firstName.text, @"firstName", self.secondName.text, @"secondname",nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", [dic objectForKey:@"firstName, secondName"]);
}

@end
```

URLOUT_Model.h

```
//
//  URLOUT_Model.h
//  URLOUT
//
//  Created by Gregory Arden on 21/11/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Not Defined. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "URLOUTViewController.h"

typedef void (^NSDictionayBlock)(NSDictionary * params);

@interface URLOUT_Model : NSObject

+ (void)createDropletWithCompletion:(NSDictionary *) params;

@end
```

URLOUT_Model.m

```
//
//  URLOUT_Model.m
//  URLOUT
//
//  Created by Gregory Arden on 21/11/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Not Defined. All rights reserved.
//

#import "URLOUT_Model.h"

@implementation URLOUT_Model

+ (void)createDropletWithCompletion:(NSDictionary *) params;
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:@{params: firstName, secondName, nil}];

    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
    [urlRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
    [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];
    [urlRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *responseData, NSError *error){

                               NSError *serializationError = nil;
                               NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                                    options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                                                      error:&serializationError];
                           }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Update your question with the code you have tried so far. Explain what isn't working and what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a HTTP PUT request is simple:

1. Create an instance of `NSMutableURLRequest`.
2. Set the HTTP method to `@"PUT"` using the `-setHTTPMethod:` method.
3. Set the header fields and body using appropriate methods (`-setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`, `-setHTTPBody:`, etc.)
4. Send the request using an instance of `NSURLConnection`.

Where the data that you send in the request comes from (text fields, data files, random number generator...) really doesn't make a difference in the creation of the request. You really shouldn't be storing data in your views, though. Generally speaking, your text views and such should trigger an action in a view controller when they change, and the view controller should update the data model. When you want to send data to some server, pull the data from the model, not from UI components.

Comment: Hi Caleb, thank you for your post. Essentialy there are two elements- the view writing to the model and the model writing to the server, both l require assistance with. I have now created a single view application and provided the classes to provide the detail around my question. Would you mind taking another look at my post? Many thanks in advance.